# WooCommerce Custom Tab with ACF Repeater Field

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a Repeater of Advance custom field for the content of the my additional custom WooCommerce Tab. The repeater is inside a group field. I manage to display the custom fields that is outside the repeater field. Now the problem is the field inside my repeater field. The repeater field is not displaying. Here is the code I used in my functions.php

// Add a Custom Tab

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'dl_custom_product_designer_tab' );
function dl_custom_product_designer_tab( $tabs ) {
    // ensure ACF is available
    if ( !function_exists( 'have_rows' ) )
        return;

    if ( get_field('designer') ) {
        $tabs[] = array(
            'title' => 'DESIGNER',
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'dl_custom_designer_tab'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

function dl_custom_designer_tab() {
    $designer = get_field('designer');
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_image'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_name'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_short_description'].'</p>';
        // loop through the rows of data
        $achievements = get_field('designer_achievements');
        if( $achievements ) {
            // loop through the rows of data
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($achievements as $achievement){
                // display a sub field value
                echo '<li>'.$achievement['achievement'].'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

Comment: is designer_achievements a field or a subfield?

Comment: can you show us a screenshot on how you created the field/subfiled ?

Comment: designer_achievement is a repeater type field then achievement is the subfield. Here is how I made the field. https://ibb.co/mGzvv6

Comment: @CKMacLeod here is the screenshot

Comment: @TemaniAfif here is the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use get_sub_field() for the repeater field (designer_achievements) and get_field() for its parent. Please take a look at the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) for the Repeater field's subfield.

You will also need to use a have_rows() loop, as noted in the documentation.

```
if( have_rows('parent_field') ):

    while( have_rows('parent_field') ) : the_row();

        $value = get_sub_field('sub_field');

    endwhile;

endif;
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that one. And sadly it is not working. I don't know if my logic is just wrong or I'm using the wrong syntax. Anyways thank you for the help.

Comment: I think you need to show your syntax. In the above example, designer_achievements would be the parent_field, and achievement would be the subfield.

Answer (score 0):

replace `$achievements = get_field('designer_achievements');` to `$achievements = get_sub_field('designer_achievements');`

Comment: Nah. Still no luck. I'll just used Wysiwyg Editor for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I search to do that and finally found a solution.You can do something like that:

This implies that your products have a repeater field "tabs"  that contains a subfield "title" and a subfield "content".

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'prefix_other_products_tab' );
function prefix_other_products_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $product;
    $additional_tabs = get_field('tabs', $product->get_id());
    foreach($additional_tabs as $index => $custom_tab){
        $slug = sanitize_title($custom_tab['title']);
        $tabs[$slug+$index] = array(
            'title' => $custom_tab['title'],
            'priority'  => 120,
            'content' => $custom_tab['content'],
            'callback'  => function($tab_name, $tab){
                global $product;
                echo $tab['content'];
            },
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```